# jQuery replace all href="" with onclick="window.location="

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a cool one for ya.

I need to scan my html document as it is rendering and replace every

```
href=""
```

with

```
onclick="window.location=''"
```

more than that, I need to carry the link from the href to the window.location.

For example, if I had:

```
href="http://www.google.com.au"
```

it would become:

```
onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com.au'"
```

and I need it to do this on **every href in the document**

---

I have no idea, but it needs to be in jQuery / javascript :D

Thanks guys.

Comment: you want to replace href with onclick, or add onclick to anchor tags..?

Comment: I need to find every anchor tag, replace the href with an onclick.

Comment: Can you give us more information on _why_ you would want to do this? As far as I know, the functionality would be equivalent, except that the new code wouldn't work with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @jfriend00 – I can't see how the page won't work if the JS is off? He'll only have removed the `href` attributes if JS is *on*.

Comment: when you have a page saved to your ipad screen as an app, and disable the safari address bar with metadata, you can only use window.location to keep it in the anti-bar browser. using an href launches the safari browser itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('onclick', "window.location='" + href + "'")
         .removeAttr('href');
});
```

What are you trying to achieve with this? Chances are that there's a more elegant way to achieve what you're after.

For example, it might be better to handle the event yourself in the JS. Replace the third line with:

```
$(this).click(function() { window.location = href; })
```

That could become very expensive though, so you might want to consider jQuery's `delegate` events: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Damn, we wrote the exact same code at the exact same time :p. Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPJCH/

Comment: Everytime somone writes things like "$(this).attr('href')` instead of `this.href` a newbie programmer somwewhere dies.

Comment: @RobG – if you're in jQuery land, play jQuery's game. Besides, that's not true for arbitrary attributes which have cross-browser quirks so it's best to make a habit of doing the safe thing. Better a newbie than a puppy anyhow.

Comment: @Dave-if you're only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail. The OP said `but it needs to be in jQuery / **javascript**`, you don't have to use jQuery for things where it makes no sense to do so. Advocating a strategy that discourages learning the environment you're programming in—even for something as simple as knowing a link has an href (which is what defines a link as a link)—doesn't sound sensible to me.

Answer (score 3):

This should achieve what you want...

```
$('a[href]').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.location = this.href;
});
```

I assume you wanted to prevent default behaviour of links.

For *all* possible links, you could use `document.links`.

For all links and future links, use event delegation.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href]', function() {
       window.location = this.href;
});
```

Comment: +1. Nice solution. Obviously more effecient than having to actually update every link.

Answer (score 2):

Some non-jQuery variants:

#### Keep href:

```
var i = document.links.length;
while (i--) 
  document.links[i].onclick = function(){window.location = this.href;};
```

#### Keep href and don't follow it if onclick called (even though it goes to the same place):

```
var i = document.links.length;
while (i--) 
  document.links[i].onclick = function() {
    window.location = this.href;
    return false;
  };
```

#### Remove href:

```
var i = document.links.length,
    link;
while (i--) {
  link = document.links[i]; 
  link.onclick = (function(href) {
    return function() {
        window.location = href;
    }(link.href));
  link.href = '';
}
link = null;
```

Of course I don't understand why you want to replace a robust, works everywhere solution with an unreliable, easily broken one.